# How to make the last row in a ReadOnly DataGrid editable

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a ReadOnly DataGrid to display some data in my WPF-application.

My question then is.

How can I make the last row editable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow_1">

private void dataGrid_LoadingRow_1(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.IsNewItem)
            e.Row.IsEnabled = true;
        else
            e.Row.IsEnabled =false;
    }
```

Comment: hi, i tried that code but i had that error : error CS1061: 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'IsNewItem' and no extension method 'IsNewItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @moez DataGridRow.IsNewItem property is not available in .NET version <= 4.0. So you need to set the Target Framework in Project->Properties to .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I have been working in windows forms not wpf and am fairly new to C# so there may be a better way to do this.

I encountered a similar problem and to get around it I made the table not read only, and then looped through all of the rows and set them individually to ReadOnly except for the last one. Not the prettiest but it worked.

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    dataRow.ReadOnly = true;
}

dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1].ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: Could you just tell me how did you set them to ReadOnly which property did you use ?

Comment: I added the code for it. Like I said though I have no experience with wpf so I'm not sure if there are any differences.