# WPF disable interacting with DataGrid's TemplateColumn for new rows before they are added

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Consider a WPF `DataGrid` with `DataGridTemplateColumn`(s) and with user initiated adding `CanUserAddRows="True"` allowed, for example

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" GroupName="OptionsRad"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Option" Binding="{Binding OptionName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `RadioButton` thanks to being hosted `DataGridTemplateColumn` can be interacted with without entering CellEditingMode, which is expected and desired. 
There is, however, the problem that on the last, 'add new option', type-of-row the `RadioButton` can be interacted with *even before new option is added* (i.e. will be added name is entered). Possibly choosing non-existent option and moving focus elsewhere. 
[image: radio]
How can I disable interacting with the template column before new row is added to bound collection?

Comment: There is a property [DataGridRow.IsNewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.isnewitem?view=netframework-4.7.2) to which you can bind with relative source ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35438666/1997232)). Means you can use datatrigger in cell template ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41335427/1997232)) to hide`RadioButton`.

Comment: @Sinatr almost - however it stays disabled forever. Cannot select any of new option(s). It appears that `DataGridRow.IsNewItem` is true on all new items not just the add-new-row. (with `Binding = "{Binding IsNewItem, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource Mode = FindAncestor, AncestorType = DataGridRow}}"`)

Comment: Seems like an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20862356/1997232), aye. Try to use event like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334547/1997232) to investigate is there a way to either change `IsNewItem` to `false` for existing items or to compare with `CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder` to determine if that it is last row and maybe set attached property value to which you [can bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5832247/1997232) trigger instead of `IsNewItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a converter to achieve what you are trying to do.

I assumed you have a class or data type to represent your `Option` data and `Options` is a collection of those items.

You could set `IsEnabled` on `RadioButton` to:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Item, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow"}, Converter={StaticResource DataToEnabledConverter}}"
```

And, the converter code would look like:

```
public class DataToEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         return value is Option;
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

Your full XAML would look like:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" GroupName="OptionsRad" 
                                     IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Item, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow"}, Converter={StaticResource DataToEnabledConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Option" Binding="{Binding OptionName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This works because `Item` property on `DataGridRow` for new rows would be of type `NamedObject`, not your data type.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up with, though there is more generic converter to do the job, as mentioned in comments, compare to `CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder`.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare with `NewItemPlaceholder` [purely in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57175186/43534) as well:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <RadioButton x:Name="Radio" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" GroupName="OptionsRad" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Item, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
                     Value="{x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}">
            <Setter TargetName="Radio" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```